# Error when trying to open multiple files in c ++

Tags: c++, file, vector

I'm trying to open multiple files to compile the data in them. My program compiles but when I run it i get the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>    what():  std::bad_alloc
>   Aborted

So far my program is pretty lengthy so I'll just link the parts of it that deal with opening the files.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
vector<Plays> yearsEntered;

Plays *MyPlays = new Plays();
if (argc < 2) 
{
    cout << "No filenames given." << endl;
    return 0;
}

for(int i=1;i < argc; ++i)
{

    string filename = argv[i];

    cout << filename << endl;

    filename.append(".csv");

    cout << filename << endl;

    ifstream inputFile(filename.c_str(), ios::in);


    inputFile.open(filename.c_str());

    //Error checking in case file fails to open
    if (!inputFile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open file. " <<
         "Try entering another file." << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure why I'm getting an error but if I had to guess i'd say it was something to do with the fact that argv[i] is a *char array and I'm setting it equal to a string. Also when i run the program it's run like this: ./Analyze 2009 2010 (etc). When i run it it'll print out the name of the file that I want to open so I know the problem is when it tries to open the file itself. This is my first time asking a question so if there's any convention I failed to follow let me know and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Can you show us a short complete example?  That code looks ok, so having something that is complete might help track down the issue in your real code.

Comment: You already opened your files once. You don't need to open them again. The `std::ifstream` constructor is opening them, then your invoking `.open()` for no reason. Remove the `inputFile.open()` line.

Comment: @WhozCraig ah, thank you so much. That was the problem. Cheers! Also, is there any way to show this question as answered?

Comment: @user2777912 yes, I'll throw an answer up. just check the green mark next to it on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already opened your files once. You don't need to open them again.

The `std::ifstream` constructor is opening each file, then your invoking `.open()` for no reason. Remove the inputFile.open() line.

Change this:

```
ifstream inputFile(filename.c_str(), ios::in);

inputFile.open(filename.c_str());
```

To this:

```
ifstream inputFile(filename.c_str());
```